# redirect from jsp to another after some time or by condition

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, redirect, javabeans

I'm a newbie in jave ee. I need the following behaviour. I've got an queue of registered users. The user on the head of queue can visit the page A 10 min. After 10 min he should be redirected to another page B and removed from queue. If this user makes logout/closes browser he should be removed from queue also.

I cannot make redirect to page B if user stays at the page A  10 min.

I'm trying to make asynchronous timer which makes redirect to B:

On the page A:

```
<h:body>
    #{CheckBean.runTimer()}
...
```

This is CheckBean:

```
public class CheckBean {
    @EJB
    ActiveUserTimer timer;
    ...
    public void runTimer() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        timer.run(externalContext, System.currentTimeMillis());
        ...
```

EJB timer:

```
@Stateless
public class ActiveUserTimer{
    @Asynchronous
    public void run (ExternalContext externalContext, long time) {
        while (true) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time > 10000 || someFuncDetectedUserIsOffline()) {
                externalContext.redirect("../public/index.xhtml");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is when I pass externalContext to run() method externalContext is not null but the externalContext.requestParameterMap value is:

> Exception occurred in target VM:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.pwc.connector.coyote.PwcCoyoteRequest.getFormHintFieldEncoding(PwcCoyoteRequest.java:225)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.pwc.connector.coyote.PwcCoyoteRequest.setRequestEncodingFromSunWebXml(PwcCoyoteRequest.java:188)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.pwc.connector.coyote.PwcCoyoteRequest.getCharacterEncoding(PwcCoyoteRequest.java:129)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseRequestParameters(Request.java:3114)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1282)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterNames(RequestFacade.java:438)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.getEntryIterator(RequestParameterMap.java:126)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.BaseContextMap$EntrySet.iterator(BaseContextMap.java:166)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.BaseContextMap$BaseSet.size(BaseContextMap.java:154)
>       at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.size(Collections.java:996)
>       at java.util.AbstractMap.size(AbstractMap.java:67)
>       at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.size(Collections.java:1276)
>       at com.mycompany.hib.ActiveUserTimer.run(ActiveUserTimer.java:29)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>           ...

I looked at Quartz but I suppose I've got the exact issue if I would pass externalContext instance.
Is there any other ways to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task doesn't require any server timer at all. You can do it using plain JavaScript. Check the [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function in order to solve your problem.

Knowing this, you can do something similar to

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { 
        document.getElementById('myForm:btnContinue').submit();
        }, 10*1000*60);
</script>

<h:form id="myForm">
    <!-- page content... -->
    <h:commandButton id="btnContinue" value="Continue" action="#{bean.continue}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: How can I delete active user from the head of queue? May I run java method via javascript? Also I should know if user leave this page earlier then timer expires.

Comment: @Alex that should be handled in your `bean#continue` method. You can even have another `bean.continueAndDelete` method that's being invoked from a hidden `<h:commandButton>`/`<h:commandLink`, but that depends on your design.